# Magento 2 - Set a custom external link in footer

Tags: magento2, xml, link

How can I set a custom external link in the footer?

Something like blog.example.com with the label of "Blog"
`<a href="blog.example.com">Blog</a>`

I have added other links to my footer via this way.

```
<referenceBlock name="footer">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer_social_links_block">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string" translate="true">dth_footer_social_links</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

I am using Magento 2.0.7 right now.

What if I use this block instead?  How could I link externally from this?  I setup a returns-policy link already - but it is internal.
    
                
                    
                        Returns and Exchanges
                        returns-policy

Comment: Explain your issue

Comment: please let me know if you have any issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it by default way

```
<referenceBlock name="footer_links">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="footer_blog_link" before="-">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Blog</argument>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">http://blog.example.com</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: I would prefer this more than static block solution.  Trying now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create one block,
I think you have already created block,

**dth_footer_social_links** open block in backend,

You can set your anchor link directly in static block,

```
<a href="http://blog.example.com">Blog</a>
```

Save Block and check in your footer.
BLog Link are display.

Comment: Valid point here, but I don't want to use that block.  I will do another static block and let you know.

Comment: create other block and check, if any problems let me know

Comment: I used your exact code in my static block.  It sent me here ```https://example.com/blog.example.com```

Comment: try with this url,http://blog.example.com

Comment: I did - here is what I put in static block - ```<a href="blog.example.com">Blog</a>```    I updated question with a "footer_links" section.  Could I use this?

Comment: please update with this, <a href="http://blog.example.com">Blog</a> add http:// before url

Comment: please let me know if issue

Comment: working!  I use https(not http) - and yes it works.